# Q/A - Edit license amount for Microsoft subscriptions without partner API - Passing ajaxsessionkey from selenium to requests module

Tags: selenium, python-requests, microsoft-graph-api

I currently use selenium to login to Microsoft admin center and increase or decrease an office subscription of my choosing; however I want to try and use just the http requests library that comes with python to make my request.

**Why I am doing this -** I can't use the partner api to increase license to due to specific circumstances. I have access to my client's MS admin account and want to use python to increase a license when creating a user using the MS graph.

What I tried -
I first tried to create http requests to login into MS....that didn't seem possible: [Logging into Microsoft Online website programatically with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035638/logging-into-microsoft-online-website-programatically-with-c-sharp) & [Difference between CSRF and X-CSRF-Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34782493/difference-between-csrf-and-x-csrf-token/34783845) I tried but seems I need to find the `xsrf token` that gets generated when using the webpage normally.

So I decided to use selenium to login to MS, then figure out how to use the `commerce API` when you are logged into MS.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.actions import action_builder
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from auths.AA_auth import interm_auth, otpauth
from selenium.common import exceptions
import time

import requests
import json
def browser_options():
    options = Options()
    options.headless = True
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    browser_options.browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    return browser_options.browser

def mslogin(msdata):
    #Go to the specific subscription in question
    browser_options.browser.get("https://admin.microsoft.com/Adminportal/Home?#/subscriptions/webdirect/ENTERSKUIDHERE")
    
    #Enter email
    ms_username = browser_options.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#i0116')
    ms_username.send_keys("ENTERADMINEMAIL")

    wait = WebDriverWait(browser_options.browser, 10)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#idSIButton9')))
    ms_usernameaccept = browser_options.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#idSIButton9')
    ms_usernameaccept.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    #Enter password
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser_options.browser, 5)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#i0118')))
    ms_password = browser_options.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#i0118')
    ms_password.send_keys("ENTERADMINPASSWORD")

    wait = WebDriverWait(browser_options.browser, 10)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#idSIButton9')))
    ms_passwordaccept = browser_options.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#idSIButton9')
    ms_passwordaccept.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    #Getting past the reduced password inquiry webpage
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser_options.browser, 5)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#idBtn_Back')))
    reducedlogingcancel = browser_options.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#idBtn_Back')
    reducedlogingcancel.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(1)

    #Get cookieinfo
    request_cookies_browser =  browser_options.browser.get_cookies()
    browser_options.browser.close()
    print(request_cookies_browser)

    s = requests.Session()
    for cookie in request_cookies_browser:
        s.cookies.set(cookie['name'], cookie['value'])

    X = ENTERNUMBERHERE

    patchheaders = {
                "accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*",
                "content-type": "application/json",
            }
    licenseincrease = {
        "totalLicenses":X
    }
    licenseincrease_json = json.dumps(licenseincrease)
    getlicense = s.patch("https://admin.microsoft.com/fd/commerceapi/my-org/subscriptions/ENTERSKUIDHERE", headers=patchheaders, data=licenseincrease_json)
    getlicense_json = getlicense.json()
    print(getlicense_json)
```

However I was getting an error:

```
{Message: "There was an error processing the request.", StackTrace: "", ExceptionType: ""}
```

Is there something I am missing to fix this issue? OR Is there a better method to use the commerce API using http requests?

NOTE: (This is setup as a question and answer. If you have a better method of doing this please leave an answer or comment below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a patch request with the commerce api (when logged into MS) you need to add the `s.AjaxSessionKey` to the request. After you add the key, it should return back the subscription json data where you can check the total license amount:

```
patchheaders = {
                "accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*",
                "content-type": "application/json",
                "ajaxsessionkey":s.cookies.get("s.AjaxSessionKey")
            }
```